# Change select when use clicks on table

Tags: jquery, forms, select

I need away to change the selected value on a drop down select.

by default it is selected on VIC but when I click on an address in NSW i would like to have the drop down select NSW in the Drop down, the only issue is the values are 1-7 not the name of the state.

I tried the following

> $("select").val('NSW').change();

and many more including triggers and more

Answer (score 1):

Use this function. Pass two parameter, first combo name and second value which you want to get selected. When you click on NSW address call this function

```
function setSelectedIndexByTextValue(comboName, comboValue) {
    var tComboName = document.getElementById(comboName);
    for (i = 0; i < tComboName.options.length; i++) {
        if (parseInt(tComboName.options[i].text) == comboValue) {
            tComboName.options[i].selected = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm assuming you have HTML that looks like this:

```
Please select a state:
<ul>
    <li>New York</li>
    <li>Pennsylvania</li>
    <li>Ohio</li>
    <li>California</li>
    <li>Washington</li>
    <li>Alaska</li>
    <li>Hawaii</li>
</ul>

<select name="state">
    <option value="1">New York</option>
    <option value="2">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="3">Ohio</option>
    <option value="4">California</option>
    <option value="5">Washington</option>
    <option value="6">Alaska</option>
    <option value="7">Hawaii</option>
</select>
```

​When you click on the California `li`, you want to select the fourth option? Easy enough: just create a simple array that maps the indices to names:

```
var map = [null, "New York", "Pennsylvania", "Ohio", "California",
          "Washington", "Alaska", "Hawaii"];
```

Then, use the `$.inArray` function to find the index that corresponds to a state:

```
var index = $.inArray($(this).html(), map);
```

Then, set the select to the option with the index you just found:

```
$("select").val(index);
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3fTAh/)

Comment: Ok but what if they are not in an array